given $x_0,...,x_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y_0,...,y_n\in\mathbb{R_{+}}$ then there exists a nonnegative polynomial with deg $\leq 2n$ s.t. $p(x_i)=y_i$
I have the following question:

let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ different points and $y_0,\dots,y_n \in \mathbb{R}$ nonnegative points show that there exists non-negative polynomial $p$ with $\deg(p) \leq 2n$ s.t. $$p(x_i)=y_i$$ for all $i$

My attempt:
From Newton interpolation there is polynomial $\tilde{p}$ with $\deg(\tilde{p}) \leq n$ s.t. $$\tilde{p}(x_i)=y_i$$ for all i.
So now I thought to add some conditions about $\tilde{p}^{\prime}$, at first I thought to add that $\tilde{p}^{\prime}(x_i)=0$ for all $i\geq1$, but it not necessarily give us what we wanted.
So after that I thought to add that $\tilde{p}^{\prime}(\frac{x_{i}+x_{i+1}}{2})=y_{i}+y_{i+1}+1$ for all $i$ (that way $\tilde{p}$ will increase after $x_i$ and decrease after $\frac{x_{i}+x_{i+1}}{2}$ and so on), but $\tilde{p}$ not necessarily will increase right after $x_i$ so it can decrease to be negative and after that increase to $y_{i}+y_{i+1}+1$
I'm really struggle with that question I thought about that some hours already, I'll be glad for some help
Thank you in advance!

Take apolynomial of degree less than n such that $p(x_i)=\sqrt{y_i}$ and square it.

Nice, Thank you :)
